# SQL Query to find work in text format

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ms-access

I need your assistance to find word from text file and get the all latter.

I have my code as it is working fine but I need to continue to search on the all text not only when it find the value.

my query is below

```
SELECT [test].Contents, [test].Subject, Mid(Contents,InStr(1,Contents,"KB"),9) AS KBs
FROM [test]
```

so the value should like KB5212512
Now I need to get the all value in the text not only the first result. Thanks

Comment: `instr` function is existing into `oracle`, not `SQL Server`, plz modfiy tha tags via adding only appropriate tags

Comment: A SQL query isn't the tool for this job.  Not just that it's not the best tool - I can't think of a way to do it.  If someone can I'll be interested to see it.  You may want to look at writing a table-valued user-defined function (which takes a string and returns a table of the substrings you want); you could use *that* in a query.  Or just query the `Contents` value and process it client-side

Comment: @AmrElsayed It would be easier to produce a query for this if I knew how the raw data was structured.

Comment: use a [string splitter](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) to take that comma separated list and place it into a column... and start normalizing your data to prevent this.

Comment: @AmrElsayed Do I understand this correctly? There is one big text with several KB-Numbers. You want to extract all the text between one KB-Number and the next KB-Number (or the end) and store this in extra columns? Something like a split-approach? Are there always 6 digits behind KB? Might be solved with `PATHINDEX()` with a pattern like `KB[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`... Please provide a sample text and the expected output.

Comment: Sorry, it's `PATINDEX`, not `PATHINDEX`. And one more hint: Your code looks like `ms-acces-SQL`. Please be carefull with your tags. `sql-server` might be misleading...

Comment: @Shnugo. Please find the text that i have to extreact the all KBs number from it.
      PATCHES/WORKAROUNDS:

    o December, 2016 Security and Quality Rollup for Microsoft .NET Framework
      4.5.2 on Windows Server 2012 for x64 (KB3205403)
Microsoft .NET Framework
      4.5.2 on Windows Server 2012 for x64 (KB3205254)
Microsoft .NET Framework
      4.5.2 on Windows Server 2012 for x64 (KB3205418)

so I have to extract the all KBs number in a new column. that's all.

Comment: @AmrElsayed That means: Each text has a `(KB000000)` at the end and you'd like to extract three rows with two columns, one for the KB-code and the other with the text. Is this correct?

Comment: @Shnugo Yes exactly as you said.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, this should work:

```
SELECT [test].Contents, [test].Subject, 
Mid(Contents,InStr(1,Contents,"KB"),Len (Contents)-InStr(1,Contents,"KB")+1) AS KBs
FROM [test]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is not working!
On the other words. I have 3 words inside text file as KB123456, KB112233, KB445566 for example. so I need to find these word by searching with any word starts with KB* and but the result in new column in the DB

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses a function to extract the correct KB codes:

```
create Procedure ReplaceValuesInAllColumns (@OldStr as nvarchar(100), @NewStr as nvarchar(100), @WHERE as nvarchar(max), @db as SYSNAME, @tName as SYSNAME)
as
begin
declare @rSQL as nvarchar(max)
set @rSQL ='
declare @cName as nvarchar(100)
declare @sql as nvarchar(max)
declare cCursor cursor for  select c.name 
        from [' + @db + '].sys.columns c 
        inner join [' + @db + '].sys.objects o on c.object_id = o.object_id 
        left join [' + @db + '].sys.identity_columns ic on c.object_id = ic.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
        where c.is_computed = 0
        and o.name = ''' + @tname + '''
        and ic.object_id is null and o.type=''u''
open cCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM cCursor INTO @cName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
    ' +
    iif (@OldStr is not null, ' set @sql = ''Update [' + @db + ']..[' + @tName + '] SET ['' + @cname + ''] = REPLACE(['' + @cname + ''],''''' + @OldStr + ''''',''''' + @NewStr + ''''')'
    ,' set @sql = ''Update [' + @db + ']..[' + @tName + '] SET ['' + @cname + ''] = ''''' + @NewStr + ''''''
    ) + 
    iif (@WHERE is not null, ' WHERE ['' + @cname + ''] LIKE ''''%' + @WHERE + '%'''''
    ,'') +  '''

    exec(@sql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM cCursor INTO @cName
    end
close cCursor
deallocate cCursor'
exec(@rSQL)
end
```

> --To change a prefix exec ReplaceValuesInAllColumns 'OlDPREFIX_', 'NEWPREFIX', null, 'MyDB', 'MyTable'
>
> --To change a NULL exec ReplaceValuesInAllColumns NULL, 'UNDEFINED', null, 'MyDB', 'MyTable'
>
> --To filter the column exec ReplaceValuesInAllColumns 'ID6600', '6600', 'PHONE', 'MyDB', 'MyTable'

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is not working! On the other words. I have 3 words inside text file as KB123456, KB112233, KB445566 for example. so I need to find these word by searching with any word starts with KB* and but the result in new column in the DB

Answer (score 0):

This will use an recursive CTE to work down the string:

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'PATCHES/WORKAROUNDS: o December, 2016 Security and Quality Rollup for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows Server 2012 for x64 (KB3205403) Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows Server 2012 for x64 (KB3205254) Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows Server 2012 for x64 (KB3205418)';

DECLARE @KBPattern NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'%(KB[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%)%';

WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT LEFT(@string,PATINDEX(@KBPattern,@string)+10) AS Part
          ,SUBSTRING(@string,PATINDEX(@KBPattern,@string)+12,4000) AS Rest
    UNION ALL
    SELECT LEFT(recCTE.Rest,PATINDEX(@KBPattern,recCTE.Rest)+10) AS Part
          ,SUBSTRING(recCTE.Rest,PATINDEX(@KBPattern,recCTE.Rest)+12,4000) AS Rest
    FROM recCTE
    WHERE PATINDEX(@KBPattern,recCTE.Rest)>0
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(Part,posKB,15) AS KB_Number
      ,LEFT(Part,posKB-1) AS KB_Text
FROM recCTE
OUTER APPLY(SELECT PATINDEX(@KBPattern,Part)) AS A(posKB)
```

The result

```
KB_Number   KB_Text
(KB3205403) PATCHES/WORKAROUNDS: o December, 2016 Security and Quality Rollup for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows Server 2012 for x64 
(KB3205254) Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows Server 2012 for x64 
(KB3205418) Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 on Windows Server 2012 for x64
```